# MiKTeX 2.90 installation fails but unclear why

Tags: miktex, installing

I am trying to install MiKTeX 2.9 on a Windows 10 PC. I had a previous installation on this machine, which I believe I deleted in its entirety.

The first couple of times I got error messages. One apparently suggested a path error of some sort.  The other may have been related to the prior installation. (I stupidly didn't copy the relevant messages, and I can't reproduce specific errors.)

I saw a post that suggested changing the "ask me first" option in the installation process might be the culprit — I had changed it — so I switched back to the default.

In any event, I ran the install file again and everything seemed to work okay. However, all was not okay. When I opened the MiKTeX console and checked for updates, I got an unhelpful (to me) popup: "Sorry, something went wrong. Do you want to see the error details?" That led me to the following:

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
ReportDate: 2022-09-27 14:16:39
CurrentVersion: 22.7
SetupDate: 2022-09-27 10:52:00
SetupVersion: 2.9
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 07c2f18 / 2022-07-16 08:47:18
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 19044
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\Art\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Art\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Art\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Art\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: non-existing/explorer

ERROR DETAILS
Program: miktex-console
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\papersize.cpp:243
Error: C:\jenkins\workspace\miktex\windows\build\source\Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\papersize.cpp:243: internal error
```

I have no c:\jenkins directory, and I am not sure what to do with this info. (In the setup, however, I had changed the default paper size from A4 to letter, but re-running the install with the default A4 didn't help.)

Online searching didn't help me either. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.